# Throttling valve speed in a refrigeration cycle

Tags: cooling-system

I'm trying to understand the general refrigeration cycle which includes a throttling valve for the freon that is controlled by a stepper motor which is done by a temperature control. I was wondering does this stepper motor's velocity is constant or does it accelerate according to the temperature sensor in the reservoir?

Answer (score 1):

The throttling valve has to control the rate of fluid movement around the system to achieve the required temperatures set by the driver in the cabin, so the velocity of the stepper motor is fairly slow - it does not need to have a rapid response as the temperature change in the cabin is slow. A slow = cheap stepper motor is sufficient for this type of task. The same argument can be given for one of the stepper motors controlling the the airflow flaps in the heater - it is not a rapid response - especially as if it closes a flap quickly it could be noisy , slow can equate to gentle...